# content://sms/sent/ not working

Tags: android, sms, observer-pattern

This is the SMS observer code. I need to check only sent sms. When I use the `content://sms/` I get the result. But why don't I get results when I use the `content://sms/sent/`? I'm using Android 2.1.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class smsSentService extends Service 
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver;
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, new contentObserver(handler));
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class contentObserver extends ContentObserver
    {
        public contentObserver(Handler handler) 
        {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) 
        {                   
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!!!", content);
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it meant to be content://sms/out ?

Comment: content://sms/out doesn't work also.

Comment: @XXX how u resolved your issue same issue content://sms/sent not working in lollipop too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://gbandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java

That code listens for changes to the whole of content://sms and checks the type to see if it is a sent message.

Comment: @giggsey Why is it that you cannot observe content://sms/sent?

Comment: @gonzobrains You can, and I have. Although neither is an official way of doing so.

Comment: I understand it's unofficial but that is okay for my purposes.  Unfortunately, onChange() doesn't get called for me when I specify "sent" after "sms" in the URI.

Comment: Broken link above.

Comment: @powder366 Found a mirror on GitHub, no idea if it's up to date: https://github.com/scrack/gbandroid/blob/master/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java